# Rhodes app signing for BlackBerry

Tags: signing, blackberry-jde, rhomobile, rhodes

I read that BlackBerry signing keys can be only installed on one PC.

I'm compiling my Rhomobile Rhodes app on one PC. But the BlackBerry signing keys are installed on another PC. What I need to do in order to sign the app on another PC.

PS: I've set bbsignpwd in `rhobuild.yml`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, its possible to copy signing files from other PC to your PC and use them for signing (of course as long as the users trust each other).

Answer (score 0):

As per Blackberry guideline you have to create build from the PC on which Blackberry signing keys is installed.